# English expressions like "Шла Саша по шоссе и сосала сушку", "Мама мыла мою малину"

Tags: произношение, английский

I'm a native Russian speaker and I have question for those whose mothertongue is English. Can you recollect some **English phrases or expressions** with complicated sound and articulation? The Russian examples are *"Шла Саша по шоссе и сосала сушку", "Мама мыла мою малину"* - the first one is a tongue twister (or a patter, I don't know really) and the second is just a testing phrase for different speech systems. I need english phrases which are **hard to pronounce/have many different sound combinations and to understand when you listen to them** (they may as well include some omophones such as night-knight).

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Hello @Peppermoon, unfortunately your question is off topic here... Try asking the same on [English Language and Usage](http://english.stackexchange.com/?as=1).

Comment: However, I can remember one - "Betty bought the butter, but the butter was bitter, so Betty bought another butter, and the new butter Betty bought was better, than the bitter butter Betty bought before." or something like this...

Comment: Hello @Umari, thank you for your answer and advice. I will ask there

Comment: =) You're welcome. Anyway, thanks for joining RL&U =)

Comment: @Peppermoon, don’t ask just yet. We’ll see if this can be migrated over there by a moderator.

Comment: But there is one shorty: “She sells seashells by the seashore”.

Comment: That's called _скороговорка_ in Russian and _tongue twister_ in Engish. Tons of English tongue twisters can be found [here](http://www.uebersetzung.at/twister/en.htm).

Comment: My favourite one is "Can you imagine an imaginary menagerie manager imagining managing an imaginary menagerie?"

Comment: Three witches watch three Swatch watch switches. Which witch watch which Swatch watch switch?